# Does the nexus player support NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-tv

According to 
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering
it states there is no support for the NDK; however my app works perfectly fine on my Nexus Player.

Google has changed their names of their device too many times and I am now confused if this document is referring to the nexus player, or to the 'old' google tv, such as the logitech revue type of devices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering it states there is no support for the NDK

That is a link to the documentation for Google TV.

> however my app works perfectly fine on my Nexus Player

The Nexus Player runs Android TV, which is not Google TV.

> I am now confused if this document is referring to the nexus player, or to the 'old' google tv, such as the logitech revue type of devices...

It is referring to the Logitech Revue, ASUS Cube, and other Google TV devices, not the Nexus Player or other Android TV devices. It also does not refer to Chromecast or other devices (should any come to pass) that plug into TVs but only support the Cast SDK and not the full Android TV experience.

(yes, this is all very confusing)

My understanding is that the NDK supports Android TV as of NDK revision 10c.

Comment: If Android TV uses the normal, existing ABIs, one doesn't need NDK r10c either - any older ones which can produce binaries compatible with the same ABI should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching googleTV for everything, and this will help me very much! Here is a slideshow that walked me through things (that was orginially contradicting my other link) http://www.slideshare.net/ph0b/developing-for-android-tv-and-the-nexus-player

Comment: @mstorsjo: I was under the impression that some keycodes pertaining to Android TV were added in NDK r10c ("Added more TV keycodes: android/keycodes.h" in the r10c release notes). Then again, I haven't looked to see what codes were added and whether or not they would be essential for many apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ah, right. Yes, for full-native apps those might be more or less essential, while for mainly-java apps with some native bits (e.g. for some computational parts or so) it shouldn't matter.